# How can I set a Listview with each cell with a separate white background?

Tags: javascript, android, material-design

I want to achieve something similar as shown in the image below. Look at how each cell is enclosed on a white, paper-like background. I guess this has something to do with Material Design guidelines. How do I proceed towards it?

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZKID.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material Design is a classy guideline on how your UI & UX has to be to give an appealing look.

A simple way to create a card view with the spaces can be done by-

```
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

More detailed code-

[Creating Lists and Cards](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

[Getting Started With RecyclerView and CardView on Android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)

Demo-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The layout for each item of the list should be a cardview. You can take a look over android documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView

Your list item layout can look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
... >
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and inside the CardView widget you can add your other elements.

Comment: This is currently a link only answer. Please bring the relevant parts into your answer.

Comment: The CardView anchor in the link was the relevant part

Comment: Now it is more substantial.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cardview or give the top margen of your layout which you are inflate in adapter

I am 100% sure You will get white diveder

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/manageProRequestRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

And Your Adapter Layout i Like  This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_avarage"
    android:background="#00706b">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_avarage"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="ID" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="Product Service" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="Category" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="Subcategory" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="Quantity" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_large"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_avarage">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="13" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="Bags &amp; luggage" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="Laptop bags" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:text="5" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/view"/>
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/color_button_selector"
                android:text="View"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_big"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_light" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/dark_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/remove"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/cancel"/>
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/color_button_selector"
                android:text="Remove"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_avarage"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_big"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/outline" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Custom listview, to achieve this we will use normal activity and layout xml file to customize listview.

In normal activity xml file set the background of Layout to some colour,
for example i am assuming activity xml as activity_main.xml

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#bdbdbd" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#bdbdbd"
        android:dividerHeight="3dip"></ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

in **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
 {

 ListView listView;
 ArrayList<MyData> list = new ArrayList<MyData>();
 MyOrderAdapter myadapter;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

listView =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

//add the data to setter and getter class,

    list.add(new MyData("Name","Desc")); //here i am ading only one row,   you can do this in loop for multiple rows

myadapter = new MyOrderAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.my_custom_list,list); //myadapter is adapter class used for custom display

 //my_custom_list is .xml file used to display the listview row in customised way, need to create new xml file
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setAdapter(myadapter);
    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

create **MyData.java** class

```
public class MyData {

String name,desc;

public MyData(String name, String desc) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

}
```

**my_custom_list.xml**

This is the xml file where you design how you want to see the listview row, each row will be displayed based on this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#00000000"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="Name" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="Desc" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**MyOrderAdapter.java**

public class MyOrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<MyData> data = new ArrayList<MyData>();


        public MyOrderAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<MyData> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
            }
        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc);



        row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final MyData mCon = data.get(position);


        holder.name.setText(mCon.getName));

        holder.desc.setText(mCon.getDesc));

        return row;
        }
        static class UserHolder {
            TextView name,desc;
            }

    }
```

This will display listview in same pattern as you mentioned.